# mean comparison table by group

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an easy way to create a table, comparing means of different variables (e.g. for gender groups):

E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['obs'] = range(1,1001)
df['gender'] = np.random.choice([1,2],1000)
df["salary"] = np.random.normal(15000, 5000, 1000)
df["Y_education"] = np.random.normal(8, 3, 1000).astype(int)
```

where the table should look something like (values are not calculated but just filled for illustration):

```
Variable                 Male(1)   Female(2)
Salary_mean              15820     16852
Salary_sd                 3620      2450
Years_of_Education_mean    9         8
Years_of_Education_sd      1.5       2
```

I know about `.groupby`, but this does not lead to such a table as far as I can apply it.

Comment: You mean need look at pivot_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df_out = df.groupby('gender')[['salary', 'Y_education']].agg(['mean', 'std'])
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df_out.T.rename(columns={1:'Male(1)', 2:'Female(2)'}))
```

Output:

```
gender                 Male(1)     Female(2)
salary_mean       15187.741741  14919.403236
salary_std         4897.463288   5161.409774
Y_education_mean      7.607350      7.548654
Y_education_std       2.877772      3.102538
```